# Loading view from cache causes 500 internal server error when using Carbon\Carbon inside blade

Tags: laravel, caching

I have a 4.2.17 version of **laravel** that was working perfectly fine for months. All of a sudden one of the views is returning a `500 server error`, and is not logging anything into the storage/logs file (already checked all permissions).

I was able to manually track down the line causing the error and it turned out to be `carbon\carbon` that was causing the issue. For some reason it was crashing when I call `Carbon:now()` from a view. So I thought it might be carbon that was causing the issue or not loading properly.

However, `Carbon:now()` only crashes the app when it is being loaded from storage/cache.

If i go into storage/cache and delete everything and refresh, the page will work including the carbon line. Once i try and refresh a second time with files now in the cache folder, I will get the `500 server error`.

If I remove all the carbon lines the page loads perfectly fine from cache.

This was all working perfectly before so I am not sure why it broke. Does anyone have any ideas? Is this an issue with loading from cache? Is there a better way I should be clearing it?

Thank you in advance for any help. Cheers.

Comment: why you just dont keep the carbon stuff on the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a timeout issue, I guess loading from cache + carbon turned out to be too much for the server. Increasing max_execution_time did the trick.